# Number of integral values of x satisfying the inequality

Tags: inequality

What is the number of integral values of $x$ satisfying the inequality:

$$\frac{(e^x-1)(\sin(x)-2)(x^2-5x+4)}{x^2(-x^2+x-2)(2x+3)}\le 0$$

I was able to find three solutions: $0$, $1$ and $4$. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes , thanks sir

Comment: Function is not defined at $0$

Comment: But 0/0 is zero I think it is defined

Comment: So what's the value of your function at $0$?

Comment: The function behaves like $1/x$ around $0$.

Comment: Values is simply zero

Comment: Why $0$? Try plotting just $(e^x-1)/x^2$ The function has a discontinuity at $0$. On one side it goes to $+\infty$, on the other side it goes to $-\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the $x^2$ in the denominator ensures the function is not defined at $x=0$, otherwise has no effect on the inequality, so we may ignore it.  Similarly, $\sin x -2$ is always negative, and so is $-x^2+x-2$, so both may be together ignored.  As $e^x-1$ has the same sign as $x$, essentially we can substitute that, and equivalently solve for
$$\frac{x(x-1)(x-4)}{2x+3} \leqslant 0$$

The intervals to check are $x< -\frac32,x \in (-\frac32, 0), x \in (0, 1), x \in [1, 4]$ and $x> 4$, which is easily done to get $x \in (-\frac32,0) \cup [1, 4]$, so integral solutions are $x\in \{-1, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$.